# Collect strings to a list within a for loop

Tags: python

I'm reading a file where I parse for specific string in each line. 
In each line the specific string is found. Now I'm trying to collect those strings into one list, but it's not working.

```
with open('readfile.txt',"r") as data:
myList = []

for lines in data

    myValues = re.findall(.......)  #that's so far OK, regex finds data of interest

    collect_ToList = myList.append(myValues)

    print(collect_ToList )
```

output:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Debug Info:

```
print(type(myValues))
```

outputs:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `print(myList)`

Comment: Change `collect_ToList = myList.append(myValues)` to `myList.append(myValues)` and add print(myList) after the loop.

Comment: `myList.append(myValues)` does not return anything, so assigning it to a variable will always give you `None`

Comment: @Akavall: Oh this is correct! It was my misconception!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myList.append(item)` adds `item` to `myList`, no need to save the output in a variable like `collect_ToList`.

```
with open('readfile.txt',"r") as data:
    myList = []
    for lines in data:
        myValues = re.findall(.......)
        myList.append(myValues)
print(myList)
```

You can also do it in one line:

```
with open('readfile.txt',"r") as data:
    myList = [re.findall(.......) for lines in data]
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

A list's `append` function returns None while it seems that you are expecting a list, remember that lists are mutable.

Try printing `myValues` or `myList` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`append` modifies a list and returns `None`.

> `append(object) -> None -- append object to end`

Therefore change:

```
collect_ToList = myList.append(myValues)
print(collect_ToList )
```

into:

```
myList.append(myValues)
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `collect_ToList = myList.append(myValues)`, you're modifying `myList`, but list.append returns None, which is assigned to `collect_ToList`.

If you want to print the values you're appending, just do `print(myValues)`.

If you want to print `myList`, use `print(myList)`.

If you want to save the contents of `myList` extended by `myValues` to a new variable, use `myExtendedList = myList + myValues`.